# Hide sandbox filesystem hierarchy

Tags: linux, sandbox

I want to hide sandbox application's file system hierarchy from others accessing it.

I have linux kernel 2.6.36. 
I sandboxed applications by identifying the resources, kept under the folder [ex /jail/networkdaemon/], shared the necessary directories by mounting as normal. Sandbox works fine after calling chroot. Now I can see my sandboxed application works fine.
I am able to list and access the sandbox application's file system hierarchy like below.

/jail/networkdaemon

```
bin

dev

etc

lib

mnt.
```

How can i hide sandbox application's file system hierarchy from others accessing it.

If need to provide more information please inform.
Thanks in advance.

Regards

Eswar

Answer (score 1):

If you want that nobody (except root) could access to your jailroot, you should do (as root):

```
chown root:root /jail/networkdaemon/
chmod 700 /jail/networkdaemon/
```